# Is it possible to create a uvm-test dynamically from a string pased via UVM_TESTNAME but then override the base-test with the newly crearted test?

Tags: command-line-interface, system-verilog, uvm

I have a use case as follows

1. There is a base test that takes lots of +args to run the sequence
2. I don't want to write separate test cases for each different +args combination but want to run the test with the name passed from +UVM_TESTNAME

for example, Here I only have the base_test class written, but the commands I pass are

```
 eg1: make run +UVM_TESTNAME=test_mode1 +arg=mode1 
 eg2: make run +UVM_TESTNAME=test_mode2 +arg=mode2
```

Now the Testbench should create/override the base test with new test called "test_mode1" or "test_mode2"

How could we get this working?

I tried the following:

```
case1: make run +UVM_TESTNAME=test_mode1 +arg=mode1 +testname=base_test // for this case there is no class "test_mode1" . 

case2: make run +UVM_TESTNAME=test_mode2 //For this case I have a class written with the name "test_mode2 "

initial begin

if($value$plusargs("testname=%s",test_arg)) begin

  // I would like to create a test with the name UVM_TESTNAME and run it
  run_test(test_arg); // this should run the newly created test
end
else run_test(); // case2 should run as normal uvm-flow

end
```

The issue is uvm take higher precedence for UVM_TESTNAME over test_arg

Comment: You need to explain why you do not use `+UVM_TESTNAME=base_test` and pass the other arguments. If this is because of the way your regression system names tests, there should be ways around that.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to set up a regression system, but now I managed to find a way to go forward. The fix is done in the makefile and the testlist(yaml) . Now I always run the base_test using +UVM_TESTNAME=base_test, but the test name for the regression system will be given another name. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain why you do not use +UVM_TESTNAME=base_test and pass the other arguments. If this is because of the way your regression system names tests, there should be ways around that. Look at the particular setup of your makefile or run scrips